# regex to find function arguments inside php files

Tags: php, regex

Can anybody help with a valid regex ?

I have a files containing functions like this one

```
$variable1 = tr ('This was written in % s . ', array ( $year ));
```

or

```
tr ('This was written in % s % s . ' ,array ( $month , $year ));
```

or

```
tr('some string ')
```

Strings are always in single quotes.

I need from the text of source which i get with fopen fundtion to extract all  strings passed to `tr()` function. I use php to parse php files. Any help?

UPDATE WOrks:

```
          $fileContents=file_get_contents($file);              


          preg_match_all("/tr\('(.*?)'/", $fileContents, $matches);

          //preg_match_all('/(?<=tr\s?\(\s?\')(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\'])*(?=\')/i',        $fileContents, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

exit(json_encode($matches));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a regex to match strings passed into a function called `tr()`.

The following regex should do:

```
/tr\('(.*?)'/
```

So:

```
<?php
preg_match("/tr\('(.*?)'/", $fileContents, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using PHP's [Tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) functions instead of complex regexp?

Comment: no actually, I think usual regex will do... what would be pros for tokenizer?

Comment: For one, you don't need to worry about whitespace (or whether it's single quote or double quote) or whether the result is assiged to a variable or not, or whether there's nested function calls within the arguments. Another argument for using the PHP tokenizer is that it's almost certainly going to be more efficient than PCRE when searching for PHP code... but it all depends why you need this